# Adding namespace in root gets copied to child nodes

Tags: templates, xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

In below example which I found on this site, an empty **xmlns=""** gets copied in all child nodes. What can the reason be for this mistake?

My Template:

```
     <xsl:element xmlns="http://www.element-examples.org" name="{local-name()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
```

OUTPUT:

```
    <projectgegevens xmlns="http://www.element-examples.org">
      <idopdracht **xmlns=""**>28062262</idopdracht>
      <projectcode **xmlns=""**>160622</projectcode>
      <projectnaam **xmlns=""**>FF0000390001</projectnaam>
      <ordernummer xmlns="">M2M-2022010071</ordernummer>
      <projectleider xmlns="">FF000039003</projectleider>
      <opmerking xmlns=""></opmerking>
      <status xmlns="">5</status>
      <datumverwacht xmlns="">2022-06-29</datumverwacht>
      <certificaatnummer xmlns="">2020083810</certificaatnummer>
      <analysemonsters xmlns="">
```

Comment: We neither know which input you have nor how you process it (as `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` just means you process attributes and child nodes), but usually that problem occurs if you copy nodes from the input in no namespace to the output where the parent now is in a namespace, the serializer then adds the `xmlns=""` to keep the copied elements in the non namespace. So don't copy, transform to change the namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't tell you specifically what you did wrong without seeing all your code, but the namespace declaration `xmlns=""` is generated by the serializer when it finds that the result tree has an element in no namespace, whose parent is in a namespace (but with no prefix).

To find out why the child elements are in no namespace, rather than in the same namespace as their parent, you need to look at the XSLT code that creates the child elements. Note that the namespace of an element is determined entirely by the instruction that creates the element; it is never inherited automatically from the namespace of its parent element in the result tree (though it may be inherited from the parent element in the stylesheet).

Comment: Thanks I am trying to add the xmlns in an earlier stage